# Convert ByteArrayOutputStream to json in Kotlin

Tags: json, jackson, kotlin

I'm trying to create a resource for 2 services, 1 in application/x-www-form-urlencoded and string payload and the other application/json format with json body.

I have this code:

```
@POST @Path("/test")
fun test(@Context request: ContainerRequest): Response {
    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    request.entityStream.use { it.copyTo(baos) }
    val ipnRawData = baos.toString()
    var map : Map<String,Any>
    map = when (request.headers.getFirst("Content-Type")) {
        "application/json" -> objectMapper.convertValue(ipnRawData,Map::class.java) as Map<String,Any>
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -> LinkedHashMap()
        else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }
    //....handle the map
    return Response.status(200).build()
}
```

But when I try to run it with the json option, and body: `{"name" :"test"}`), I get an error:

> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not construct instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{
>   "name" :"test"}')"

Thanks for any help, Yoel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `mapper.readValue` to deserialize JSON into an object.

Using raw Jackson **without** the [Jackson-Kotlin module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin):

```
val map: Map<String, String> = JSON.readValue("""{"name" :"test"}""",
                      object : TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {})
```

This passes in an [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) with superclass `TypeReference` specifying the the type you are wanting to create with full generics still intact (you method suffers from type erasure).

Instead, if you **are using** the [Jackson-Kotlin module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) you only need:

```
val map: Map<String, String> = JSON.readValue("""{"name" :"test"}""")
```

Since it has helper/extension functions to hide some of the uglier things like `TypeReference` creation.

**You should always use the [Jackson-Kotlin module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) with Kotlin code** so that you can instantiate any type of Kotlin object including data classes that have all `val` parameters and no default constructors, have it understand nullability, and also deal with default values for constructor parameters.  A simple stand-alone example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.*

val JSON = jacksonObjectMapper() // creates ObjectMapper() and adds Kotlin module in one step

val map: Map<String, String> = JSON.readValue("""{"name" :"test"}""")
```

Notice the import `.*` so that it picks up all the extension functions otherwise you need to explicitly import:  `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue`

**Or in your case the modified code would be:**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue

val objectMapper = jacksonObjectMappe() // instead of ObjectMapper()

... 

@POST @Path("/test")
fun test(@Context request: ContainerRequest): Response {
    val bodyAsString = request.entityStream.bufferedReader().readText() 
    val map: Map<String, Any> = when (request.headers.getFirst("Content-Type")) {
        "application/json" -> objectMapper.readValue(bodyAsString) 
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -> LinkedHashMap()
        else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }
    //....handle the map
    return Response.status(200).build()
}
```

The code has also been cleaned up a little to remove the use of a `var` and to read the entity stream in a more Kotlin friendly way.

Also note that the `Content-Type` header may be more complicated, it could contain encoding as well such as:

```
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

So you may want a utility function that checks if the header is "equal to `application/json` or starts with `application/json;`" instead of only an equality check.

Lastly you could pass the `request.entityStream` directly to `objectMapper.readValue` and never copy it into a string at all.  There are various overloads for `readValue` that are helpful for these types of inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the helpful tips!